# Does Discord has event-base webhooks api?

Tags: api, discord, webhooks

In a Discord channel, I'm attempting to gather activity statistics (the times users join and exit the voice channel).

Although I searched the Discord webhook api, I was unable to discover anything that matched my use case.

My question is does Discord provides event-base webhook api that send out data to an endpoint?(when a user joins or exits voice chanel) Or any other suggestion how to approach this?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

No, but [Gateways](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateways) has a [Voice State Update](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#voice-state-update) event that relies on WebSockets. Note that you will also need to enable the [intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents).